# Which correlation measure should be used with a large gap (missing data)?

Tags: distributions, correlation, missing-data

I am trying to correlate age (6-90 yrs) with loudness of voice (in dB). However, my data do not contain any data points in the range of 20-50 yrs.

What correlation measure is most appropriate with such a considerable gap, and why? I have been using Kendall Tau so far.

Note that we are not dealing with bimodally distributed data here, but with a substantial missing data gap in the age range.

Comment: The title mentions that there is a gap in one variable, but from the body it seems that the gap is in both variables for which you are trying to compute the correlation. So what data exactly is missing?

Answer (score 8):

**Create a scatterplot** to check whether it makes any sense to suppose that a single correlation coefficient is an adequate description of the association between the variables.

For example, in these (simulated) data the correlation for ages 6-20 is 90%, for ages 50+ it's -70%, and overall it's 15%.  In such a situation reporting a single correlation coefficient would be as deceptive as reporting that the average number of legs among household pets is four when half of the pets are fish and the other half are spiders...

[image: Scatterplot of loudness vs. age for 150 simulated people]

The choice of *how* to express correlation is of secondary concern and rests on other aspects of the dataset.

Comment: whuber is wise.  With a gap that big, I think it is almost never justified to give any importance to a single measure of correlation.

Comment: (+1) nice spider fish anecdote!